# Regex for repeated pattern separated by comma

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hey so I would like to generate a regex that repeats a pattern (`\w*:\w*`) separated by a comma. I will include some valid and invalid patterns to see in the following:

```
Valid: SomeAlpha:Abc
Valid: Aa:Bb,Cc:Dd,Ee:Ff,Gg:Hh
Invalid: Aa:Bb,Cc:Dd,Ee:Ff,
Invalid: First:oNe:NoComma
```

I currently setup the regex like this

```
\(\w*:\w*,\)*
```

However, as you can see the issue is that the pattern has to end with the comma. I tried putting `?,` but it does not validate the fourth example in the above. Is there any pattern expression that I could do in the case?

Answer (score 2):

You could write the pattern as:

```
^\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+:\w+` Match `:` between 1+ word chars
- `(?:,\w+:\w+)*` Optionally repeat the comma and the previous pattern using a non capture group `(?:`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tNiIh9/1)

Comment: thank you so much, that works. I did not know there is such thing as `(?:,` earlier

Comment: ++ve for nice answer. One question, can we use positive look ahead also for same? Just curious didn't try it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 If you want to match the whole string with the repeating pattern you can just match it instead. If you want to use a lookahead, you can assert the format and then match the whole string.